# Disallow some WordPress posts in robots.txt

Tags: wordpress, url, robots.txt

Let's say I've published a few WordPress posts with the following URLs:

http://example.com/2011/08/show_this/

http://example.com/2011/08/hide_this/

http://example.com/2009/04/hide_this_too/

If I want to hide all the posts that are named with the prefix "hide_" from search engines but show all others, how can this be achieved with robots.txt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding this to your robots.txt should do it.

```
Disallow: /*hide*
```

Comment: Good answer. Note, however, that the trailing * is not necessary. That is, `/*hide` will work, also. If you want to make sure only to get those that have the prefix "hide_", you would make it "/*/hide_".